# Think I am unable to override simple CSS changes due to VAR --primary colour

Tags: css, var

I have some experience with CSS and I have been tasked with changing our brand colours on my company's website. For the most part, I have been able to change everything with the exception of a few minor things. The issue is that when I change it in 'inspect' to test it on the website - the change works perfectly fine.

**I want to change it from:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.section-pricing .pricing-block.active {
transform: scale(1.06);
border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
```

}

**To**

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.section-pricing .pricing-block.active {
    transform: scale(1.06);
    border: 1px solid #3882F9;!important
}
```

Could this be a VAR issue and primary colour and I am unable to override? When I attempt to change the :root this doesn't work either. Can anyone tell me how I am doing this wrong?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: We'll need a bit more CSS than this. As shown, CSS vars are irreverent.

Comment: Apologies I posted the wrong initial code: @media .section-pricing .pricing-block.active {
    transform: scale(1.06);
    border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
}

Comment: Are you testing that particular ruleset with the viewport width of at least 992px or higher? If your devtools is positioned to the right, then your viewport width is most likely below 992px.

Comment: That is a good question and that's in the initial CSS and I thought it would be as easy as just adding this to the 'additional CSS' in wordpress like I've done with the other changes - '.section-pricing .pricing-block.active {
    border: Color: #3882F9; !important
 }' but for some reason it just doesn't take. When I test it on the website inspect with that small change it works fine